# How to retrieve session in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Edit function

```
 public function editNotice(Request $request,$id=null){
   if(Session::has('idSession')){
         if($request->isMethod('post')){

            $data = $request->all();
            $test = $data['death_name'];
            Session::put('death_name',$test);


    } else {
      return redirect('/user')->with('flash_message_error','Please Login First to access..');
    }
}
```

verifyEditNotice function

```
public function verifyEditNotice(Request $request,$id=null){

    $new = Session::get('death_name');
      echo $new;die;
 }
```

I have saved death name in session in edit function and I want to retrieve the session value in verify edit function.

But the problem is when I retrieve it shows null.

How do I get the value in another function..

Answer (score 2):

According to laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#retrieving-data) you can get it as like below

```
public function verifyEditNotice(Request $request,$id=null){
   $session_value = $request->session()->get('death_name');
    dd($session_value); // debug it and die 
}
```

Also laravel give you debug function `dd();` which will debug provided variable so you don't need to use `die()`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides helper functions and one of them is `session()`

Example:

```
session()->flash('success', 'This is a flash message!');
or in your case
session()->get('death_name');
```

Try dumping the variable using dd(), another very useful helper function in the Laravel framework.

Comment: it only gives null

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function editNotice(Request $request,$id=null){
     if(Session::has('idSession')){
         // 1. First try
         dd($request->all());  //check if control gets to this line


       if($request->isMethod('post')){
          // 2. Second try 
          dd($request->all());  // check if control gets to this line

          $data = $request->all();
          $test = $data['death_name'];

         // Session::put('death_name',$test);
          $request->session()->put('death_name', $test);


          ///////////////////// 3. Third try
          dd(session('death_name')); // check if control gets to this line
     } else {
       return redirect('/user')->with('flash_message_error','Please Login First to 
         access..');
    }
 }
```

Debug using above code :

if you get to the **step 3** and still gets NULL/Empty

Go to your `{project_root}/storage` folder and give `775` permission and ownership to `www-data`

Use following commands:

`{project_root}> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage/`

`{project_root}> sudo chmod -R 775 storage/`

if above doesn't work try it with `777`

if `777` also doesn't work

Verify your configuration.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#configuration